Is a ring endomorphism determined by its right inverse?
Let us consider a ring $(R,0,+,*, 1)$, a map (not necessary homomorphism) $f:R\to R$ satisfying $f(1) = 1$, $f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$ for all $x$, $y$ in $R$, and a ring homormophism $h\colon R \to R$ such that
$h(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in R$ (or shortly $h\circ f = id_R$).
Clearly, given an endomorphism $h'$ satisfying the condition ($h'\circ f = id_R$) we know that $h'|_R = h|_R$, where $X$ is a span of all finite sums and products from $Im(f)$

Does it hold that $f$ determines $h$ (implying $h' = h$)?
Or is there a ring and $f$ with two distinct
endomorphisms $h$ and $h'$ such that both are left inverses to $f$?

(Recently, I have asked a similar question for monoids/groups.)

No, even when $f$ is a homomorphism. Let $\pi$ and $\phi$ be a bijection from odd natural numbers to all natural numbers and a bijection from even natural numbers to all natural numbers, respectively. Let $f: \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ be defined by,
$$f((z_n))_m = \begin{cases} a_{\pi(m)} &, \text{ if }m\text{ is odd}\\
a_{\phi(m)} &, \text{ if }m\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$
Let $g, h: \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ be defined by,
$$g((z_n))_m = z_{\pi^{-1}(m)}$$
$$h((z_n))_m = z_{\phi^{-1}(m)}$$
Then $h \circ f = g \circ f = \text{Id}$, but $h \neq g$.
Remark: By changing $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ to its subring consisting of eventually constant sequences, we see that a counterexample can be given with $R$ being countable abelian. $R$ being finite, however, is impossible, as $g \circ f = \text{Id}$ implies $f$ is invertible with $g = f^{-1}$ in that case.

Thank you for the answer! I am wondering if there is a case where $g$ and $h$ are not "isomorphic" in the sense of the existence of a bijection $b\colon R\to R$ such that $gb = bh$.

Does such a $b$ even exist in this case…? I don’t see any natural choice of $b$ at least.

Oh, you are right! Such bijection only exists if something like $2\phi(m)+1 = \pi(2m+1)$ holds...

If we let $R = \mathsf k[x,y]$ be the polynomial ring in two variables over a field $\mathsf k$, then viewing $\mathsf k[x,y]$ as $\mathsf k[x][y]$ it is clear that $R$ has a large collection of endomorphisms $\mathsf{ev}_f\colon R \to \mathsf k[x]$ where $f\in \mathsf k[x]$: if $p(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i(x)y^i$ for $c_i(x)\in \mathsf k[x]$, then $\mathsf{ev}_f(p) :=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i(x)f^i$. Now the obvious inclusion map $\iota \colon \mathsf k[x]\to \mathsf k[x,y]$ clearly satisfies $\mathsf{ev}_f\circ \iota = \mathsf{id}_{\mathsf k[x]}$ and so clearly the right-inverse of a homomorphism is not, sufficient to recover the homomorphism.
Addendum: As David Gao rightly points out in the comments, if you wish the endomorphism to be surjective, then take $S=\mathsf k[x_n: n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}]$, the polynomial ring with countably many generators. Then we have an isomorphism $\psi\colon S\to S[x]$ given by $\psi(x_n)= x_{n-1}$ for $n>0$ and $\psi(x_0)=x$. For any $f \in S$ we can then define $\psi_f \colon S \to S$ to be $\mathsf{ev}_f \circ \psi$ where $\mathsf{ev}_f\colon S[x] \to S$ is given by $\mathsf{ev}_f(\sum_{i=0}^n s_ix^i)= \sum_{i=0}^n s_if^i$ then if $\iota\colon S \to S$ is given by $\iota(x_n)= x_{n+1}$, then $\psi_f\circ \iota(x_n)= x_n$ for all $n \geq 0$, so that $\psi_f \circ \iota= \text{id}$, but clearly if $\psi_{f_1}=\psi_{f_2}$ then $f_1 = \psi_{f_1}(x_0)=\psi_{f_2}(x_0)=f_2$.

@psl2Z I think krm2233 was thinking that $h$ could have different domain and codomain. Though this can easily be fixed by just changing $k$ to a ring $S$ with the property that $S \simeq S[x]$.
